# Expected specifier-qualifier-list before 'b3Vec'

Tags: c, struct, compiler-errors

This should be a simple one, but I can't figure out the problem.

I have a struct defining a vector in 3D space, in `vectors.h`:

```
/**
 * The struct defining vectors in 3D space.
 */
struct b3Vec {

  /**
   * The size of the vector.
   */
  double size;

  /**
   * The first direction of the vector in degrees.
   */
  double dir1;

  /**
   * The second direction of the vector in degrees.
   */
  double dir2;
};
```

In another struct, called b3World in `world.h` I have this:

```
b3Vec gravitation;
```

I'm getting the error on this line `Expected specifier-qualifier-list before 'b3Vec'`. I'm including the header files right and it's the only error I get.

Can anyone help me?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to use the `struct` keyword:

```
struct b3Vec gravitation;
```

Comment: Crap I'm forgetting this every time. :) Thanks. Wait a moment for the stupid acception-delay.